# Can you take a 5-foot step when your normal speed is 5 feet?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement

I'm planning on playing as a merfolk in a future *Pathfinder* campaign. Since merfolk only have a land speed of 5 feet, can a merfolk take a 5-foot step so as to avoid attacks of opportunity even though that's a merfolk's maximum movement?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### No

Looking at the [5-foot step entry](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#take-5-foot-step) in the PRD answers this:

> You can only take a 5-foot-step if your movement isn't hampered by difficult terrain or darkness. **Any creature with a speed of 5 feet or less can't take a 5-foot step, since moving even 5 feet requires a move action for such a slow creature.**

So no, they cannot.

Comment: That is why [d20 Hutts use hover-dais](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTwEVq6VtgA). Get your merfolk some [boots of striding and sprinting](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Boots_of_Striding_and_Springing) ..... oh, wait a second...

Comment: I had actually thought the answer would be 'yes'... good catch though!

Comment: Depending on the class an [agile alpenstock](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/wondrousItems/slotless.html#agile-alpenstock) could help.  You need to hold it in your hand for it to work.